# Python: in dataframe, how to concatenate a column across rows (col. being list of lists)?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a Dataframe as shown below as dataframe1:

**dataframe1**

| ID | PATH |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | [[orange, apple, kiwi, peach], [strawberry, orange, kiwi, peach]] |
| ABC | [[apple, plum, peach], [apple, pear, peach]] |
| BCD | [[blueberry, plum, peach], [pear, apple, peach]] |
| BCD | [[plum, apple, peach], [banana, raspberry, peach]] |

I would like to concatenate the value of column 'PATH' by column 'ID' and have the following results:

**dataframe2 (ideal output, the output is the list of lists)**

| ID | PATH |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | [[orange, apple, kiwi, peach], [strawberry, orange, kiwi, peach], [apple, plum, peach], [apple, pear, peach]] |
| BCD | [[blueberry, plum, peach], [pear, apple, peach], [plum, apple, peach], [banana, raspberry, peach]] |

I used the following code:

```py
df2 = df1.groupby('id')['PATH'].apply(list)
```

but got the results with [[[  ]]] as shown which is list of list of lists...and is not what I want.

**dataframe3 (wrong output)**

| ID | PATH |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | [[[orange, apple, kiwi, peach], [strawberry, orange, kiwi, peach], [apple, plum, peach], [apple, pear, peach]]] |
| BCD | [[[blueberry, plum, peach], [pear, apple, peach], [plum, apple, peach], [banana, raspberry, peach]]] |

How can I get the results like in dataframe2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = df.groupby("ID")["PATH"].apply(lambda x: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))).reset_index()
```

or

```py
df = df.groupby("ID")["PATH"].apply(lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]).reset_index()
```

Full working example:

```py
data=[
  ["ABC", [["orange", "apple", "kiwi", "peach"], ["strawberry", "orange", "kiwi", "peach"]]],
  ["ABC", [["apple", "plum", "peach"], ["apple", "pear", "peach"]]],
  ["BCD", [["blueberry", "plum", "peach"], ["pear", "apple", "peach"]]],
  ["BCD", [["plum", "apple", "peach"], ["banana", "raspberry", "peach"]]],
]

columns = ["ID", "PATH"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

df = df.groupby("ID")["PATH"].apply(lambda x: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))).reset_index()
#OR
df = df.groupby("ID")["PATH"].apply(lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]).reset_index()

[Out]:
 ID                                                                                                           PATH
ABC   [[orange, apple, kiwi, peach], [strawberry, orange, kiwi, peach], [apple, plum, peach], [apple, pear, peach]]
BCD              [[blueberry, plum, peach], [pear, apple, peach], [plum, apple, peach], [banana, raspberry, peach]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If im interpreting this properly you might want to look into the 'merge' function.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: Merge is for the combination of two dataframes..I tried to work on single dataframe groupby but the metric is list of lists.